# Merging master branch to current before building

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I need to merge my master branch code to current branch before building. We don't have access to Git Publisher. I wanted to know what my options are.

I looked into an advanced feature to "Merge before Build" but that seems to merge current branch to master?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is doable, but I have my doubts. Why you don't do it on your local machine? What happens if there is conflict? Will you want to commit once you merge?

Comment: There is a cron job that builds this branch everyday and I want it to use the latest code from master branch. I don't really care about commit. Thanks!